# What data type is used to store long strings in Oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am developing using .net core.
The database uses Oracle. The maximum value of varchar2 is 4000 bytes, and what data type is used to store the data above this?

I created a column using clob and mapped it to .net.

Model

```
public string CONTENTS { get; set; }
```

code

```
try
{
    var content= _mapper.Map<T_CONTENT>(post);

    _dbcontext.T_CONTENT.Add(content);
    _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
    transaction.Commit();

    return content.ID;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    transaction.Rollback();
    return null;
}

public class contentDbContext : DbContext
{
    public contentDbContext(DbContextOptions options)    : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public DbSet<T_CONTENT> T_CONTENT{ get; set; }
}
```

When I save the data, I get the error below.
error message : ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Comment: Version of .Net/.Net Core and EF? Do you use Fluent API for mapping? Post also that conf.

Comment: @Alessandro 
Added. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the mapping you can try using .HasColumnType("CLOB") with your modelBinder

Example:

```
public class ContentDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<<EntityName>>()
            .Property(a => a.<CoulmnName>).HasColumnType("CLOB");
    }
}
```

Comment: I saved it to the database in this way, but when I searched it, an error occurs.
NetworkException: ORA-12537 network session end of file exception.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me thanks.  Note that there's a minor typo in <CoulmnName>

Answer (score 1):

According to the ODP.NET EF Core [Migrations Data Type Mapping](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3/odpnt/EFCoreDataTypeMapping.html#GUID-484E9D3A-8E42-417F-9591-F2E7305E3F6A), the default `string` type mapping without data annotations / fluent configuration is `NVARCHAR2(2000)`.

Depending of the values of `IsUnicode`, `IsFixedLength` and `HasMaxLength`, it could be `CHAR[n]`, `NCHAR[n]`, `VARCHAR2[n]`, `NVARCHAR2[n]`, `CLOB` and `NCLOB`.

So if you need long strings with MaxLength >= 2000 characters, you need to either specify the max length >= 2000 with data annotations (`[MaxLength]` or `[StringLength]`, not sure which one, you have to figure out) or `HasMaxLength` fluent API - either should give you `CLOB` or `NCLOB` storage data type. Or, specify directly the storage data type via `TypeName` argument of the `[Column]` attribute, or `HasColumnType` fluent API.

From the two methods preferable is to do that via specifying max length, since it is more abstract and database agnostic, and better represents the desired behavior without dealing with database specific types.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you? Please check this.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm#REFRN10321